Flask camera webstream
I'm sending image bytes to the flask server, but when I try to change the resolution of the transferred image on the server, the image appears double (strange transparent repetition of objects in the frame). I'm just trying to speed up the transfer through lossy compression. IMPORTANT: I can't use the OpenCV library, Pillow (Including libraries that use Pillow), so I wrote png_creator_compress.py
main.py:
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.camera import Camera
from flask import Flask, Response, render_template_string
import threading
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.graphics.texture import Texture
from png_creator_compress import create_rgba_image  # Импортируйте вашу функцию здесь
import io

kivy.require('1.10.0')

app = Flask(__name__)

# Global variable to store the image data in bytes
image_data_flask = None
image_pixels = None
image_size = None

def generate_frames():
    global image_data_flask
    while True:
        if image_data_flask:
             #Stream the image da
             yield (b'--frame\r\n'
                   b'Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n' + image_data_flask + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(generate_frames(),
                    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template_string('''
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Video Streaming</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Video Streaming</h1>
        <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}">
    </body>
    </html>
    ''')

def start_flask_app():
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=3000, debug=False)

class MyApp(App):

    def updt(self, *args):
        global image_data_flask
        if self.cam.texture:  # Check if the texture is ready
            while True:
                pixels = image_pixels
                size = image_size
                print(size)

                # Convert the pixels to PNG using png_creator.py
                buffer = io.BytesIO()
                create_rgba_image(size[0], size[1], pixels, buffer)
                image_data_flask = buffer.getvalue()

    def start_th(self, *args):
        threading.Thread(target=self.updt).start()

    def after_camera_start(self, *args):
        global image_pixels
        global image_size

        # Set new dimensions
        new_width = 480
        new_height = 640

        # Create a new texture object
        new_texture = Texture.create(size=(new_width, new_height), colorfmt='rgba')
        new_texture.blit_buffer(self.cam.texture.pixels, colorfmt='rgba', bufferfmt='ubyte')

        # Get region (this automatically resizes)
        new_texture = new_texture.get_region(0, 0, new_width, new_height)

        # Get the pixel data as bytes
        image_pixels = new_texture.pixels
        image_size = new_texture.size

    def start_schedule(self, *args):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.after_camera_start, 0.1)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.start_th, 0.1)

    def build(self):
        self.window = BoxLayout()
        self.cam = Camera(play=True, resolution=(640, 480))
        self.window.add_widget(self.cam)

        # Start Flask app in a separate thread
        threading.Thread(target=start_flask_app).start()

        Clock.schedule_once(self.start_schedule, 3)

        return self.window

MyApp().run()

png_creator_compress.py:
import struct
import zlib
import io

def create_rgba_image(width, height, pixel_data, output_stream):
    # PNG Header
    png_header = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n'
    width=480
    height=640
    # IHDR Chunk
    ihdr_data = struct.pack(
        '>IIBBBBB',
        width,
        height,
        8,  # Bit depth
        6,  # Color type (RGBA)
        0,  # Compression method
        0,  # Filter method
        0   # Interlace method
    )
    ihdr_chunk = struct.pack(
        '>I4s', len(ihdr_data), b'IHDR'
    ) + ihdr_data
    ihdr_crc = struct.pack('>I', zlib.crc32(b'IHDR' + ihdr_data) & 0xffffffff)
    ihdr_chunk = ihdr_chunk + ihdr_crc

    def compress_data(data):
        return zlib.compress(data, level=6)

    def add_filtering(data):
        bytes_per_row = width * 4
        filtered_data = bytearray()
        for row in range(height):
            start = row * bytes_per_row
            end = start + bytes_per_row
            filtered_data.append(0)  # Filter type 0
            filtered_data.extend(data[start:end])
        return bytes(filtered_data)

    raw_data = pixel_data
    filtered_data = add_filtering(raw_data)
    compressed_data = compress_data(filtered_data)
    idat_chunk = struct.pack(
        '>I4s', len(compressed_data), b'IDAT'
    ) + compressed_data
    idat_crc = struct.pack('>I', zlib.crc32(b'IDAT' + compressed_data) & 0xffffffff)
    idat_chunk = idat_chunk + idat_crc

    # IEND Chunk
    iend_chunk = struct.pack('>I4s', 0, b'IEND')
    iend_crc = struct.pack('>I', zlib.crc32(b'IEND') & 0xffffffff)
    iend_chunk = iend_chunk + iend_crc

    # Write to output stream
    output_stream.write(png_header)
    output_stream.write(ihdr_chunk)
    output_stream.write(idat_chunk)
    output_stream.write(iend_chunk)


after numerous tests, I realized that this problem only exists on iOS, perhaps due to the fact that on iOS i cannot change the camera resolution self.cam = Camera(play=True, resolution=(960, 540)) (default: 1920x1080)

Are there any ways to compress an image besides changing the resolution?
